# Не работает register_next_step_handler из другого файла

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть 2 файла functions.py и bot.py Есть функция которая вызывается в bot.py из functions.py В этой функции должен работать register_next_step_handler который проводит дальше по флоу, но этого не происходит

bot.py

```
import telebot;
from telebot import types;
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
import config
import functions
import db

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token);

#BOT
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

#MESSAGE TRIGGER
def get_text_messages(message):
    functions.get_userData(message)
    #/Start
    if message.text == "/start":
        functions.startMessageFunc(message)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, functions.insertReveneu)
        #All Items SUM
    if message.text == "Сумма всех расходов":
        showAllPrices(message)
        #Add item
    if message.text == "Добавить расход":
        functions.addItemFirstStep(message)

        #SHOW CATEGORY SUM
    if message.text == 'Сумма расходов по категории':
        categoryButtons(message)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, showCategorySum)
    if message.text == 'Добавить доход':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите доход:")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, functions.insertReveneu)
    if message.text == 'Остаток':
        functions.getRemains(message)




bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

functions.py

```
#Add Item First Step
def addItemFirstStep(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введи сумму:")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, addItemSecondStep)
    print("Add Item First Step")    

#Add Item Second Step
def addItemSecondStep(message):
    functions.categoryButtons(message)
    global sum
    sum = float(message.text.replace("," , "."))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, addItemFinalStep)
    print("Add Item Second Step")
```